# I want to displaying comments for each post

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

hello I just moved from php native and want to try relationships in laravel, so I want to display a post and each comment and the name of user who comments so that when looped the post has a comment that has a relationship with it.

So this is my HomeController.php :

```
public function index() {
        
        $posts = Post::all();
        $comment = Comment::all();
        
        
        return view('home', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'comments' =>  $comment
        ]);
}
```

My Post.php :

```
 public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

  public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

My Comments.php :

```
 public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }

 public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

My User.php :

```
 public function post() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

My home.blade.php :

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="box-post">
          <p>{{ $post->user->name }}</p>
          <p>{{ $post->post_content}}</p>
          <a href="/comment/{{ $post->id }}"><button>Comment</button></a>
        </div>

        @foreach ($comments as $comment)
           <div class="box-post">{{ $comment->comment_content }} </div>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

the code above runs with the post displayed along with the author but all the comments also appear in all posts, I have searched for references and tried to change the comments value in Controller but the results are still the same so I made the comments appear in each post *`$comment = Comment::all();`.

what I want is to display posts and comments that relate to each post,  like a twitter feature that can reply to people's tweets.

Thx you..

Comment: just check the docs for eager loading or lazy loading, you'd want to do something like `Post::with(['comments', 'user'])`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I hope this url will help.
[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-relationships-with-userspostscomments](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-relationships-with-userspostscomments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relations builded well, so just can simply use  `$post->comments` can get all comments related on each post.

```php
@foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="box-post">
          <p>{{ $post->user->name }}</p>
          <p>{{ $post->post_content}}</p>
          <a href="/comment/{{ $post->id }}"><button>Comment</button></a>
        </div>

        @foreach ($post->comments as $comment) // make changes here
           <div class="box-post">{{ $comment->comment_content }} </div>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function index() {
        
        $posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
        
        
        
        return view('home', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            
        ]);
}
```

then in blade

```
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="box-post">
          <p>{{ $post->user->name }}</p>
          <p>{{ $post->post_content}}</p>
          <a href="/comment/{{ $post->id }}"><button>Comment</button></a>
        </div>

        @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
           <div class="box-post">{{ $comment->comment_content }} </div>
        @endforeach
   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done fine job building models and their relationship.

I recommend you change how you call post query.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        
        // add eager loading comments for each post and user
        $posts = Post::with('comments', 'user')->get();
        // eager loading user is needed, cause in blade you call $post->user->name
        // calling comments will no longer needed
  
        // return only $posts
        return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

And inside your blade, you can call comments from each post, like this.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="box-post">
          <p>{{ $post->user->name }}</p>
          <p>{{ $post->post_content}}</p>
          <a href="/comment/{{ $post->id }}"><button>Comment</button></a>
        </div>

        @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
           <div class="box-post">{{ $comment->comment_content }} </div>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

That's it and if you use `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` , you will see there are only 3 queries run, each one from table posts, comments and users.
And for comments query and users query, not all rows will be fetched,
only related to fetched posts from the 1st query.

Have fun using Laravel Framework!
Your PHP native knowledge/expertise will be very useful and speed up your learning/mastering process.

Comment: OHH I SEE THX YOU, I will learn more about the eager loading :)